# how can generate an object in an empty object in unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a 13-year-old game developer I was making a game [here is an early prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy2AC.png) I want to generate some object in an empty object in unity 2D

Comment: Hello, you should try and be a little more specific about what you mean. Generating an object could mean a lot of different things. Are you trying to instantiate a prefab from a script?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you should give a **more specific** about what you mean I will **try to explain as I understand what you mean** and **next time please give more details about your suggestion or problem**

if you want to generate some object you need to make creating empty in the hierarchy section after opening any script in this empty object then you need to make a prefab about what are you planning the generate object let's give some sample

```cs
 public GameObject EnemyModel;
 public GameObject EnemyPos;
 
 void Update() {
 
     if (!EnemyPos) {
         EnemyPos= Instantiate(EnemyModel, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
     }
 }
```

we are using 2 public objects first EnemyModel you should put your **Enemy prefab with position** after EnemyPos you need to put your main generator (empty object)
that's a sample of generator/spawner

useful link about Instantiate, prefab, quaternion

> [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Instantiate][about Instantiate]

> [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=prefab][about prefabs]

> [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=quaternion][about quaternion]

> source: unity documentary